# Mongoose Schema Model For Social Media Handler (How To)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've been working on building a RESTful API with Express and Mongoose. A feature of the API, is required to have user Model with a `path` of Social Media Handlers. I have implemented the `{type: Map, of: String}`. But problem with this approach is that the client can send any amount of Social Handlers on the database while we only need 8 (facebook, likedin, twitter, instagram, github... you guessed it).

So my current model is look like this:

```js
const leadSchema = new Schema(
  {
    
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    //....
    socialLinks: { type: Map, of: String },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
}
```

I know for `{type: String}` we can use something called `enum` to enforce certain values, But can we
do something with `{type: Map}`. I also know, you can write custom validation, but I cannot figure this out. **How do you write Model to enforce something like this?**

TIA.

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268350/how-to-validate-object-keys-and-values-in-mongoose-schema

Comment: Yeah. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks. @alilland